# Sum of decomposition coefficients of collinear points is $1$, but here seems to be a violation.

Tags: geometry, vectors, analytic-geometry, vector-analysis

Below is a proposition in a text on analytic geometry:

> Given two points $A$ and $B$, $A\ne B$, $O$ an arbitrary point, if point $C$ is collinear with $A$ and $B$, then vector $\overrightarrow{OC}$ can be decomposed by $\overrightarrow{OA}$ and $\overrightarrow{OB}$, and the sum of decomposition coefficients is $1$. That is, $\overrightarrow{OC}=a\overrightarrow{OA}+b\overrightarrow{OB}$ and $a+b=1$.

The text further states that the conclusion holds even if $O$ is collinear with $A$ and $B$ (I checked the proof and could find no problem), only the decomposition coefficients are not unique (but this seems to have nothing to do with my question).

Now, I put $O$ on line $\ell=\overline{AB}$. Take two points $C_1$ and $C_2$ on $\ell$, so we have $$\overrightarrow{OC_1}=a_1\overrightarrow{OA}+b_1\overrightarrow{OB} \qquad \qquad\overrightarrow{OC_2}=a_2\overrightarrow{OA}+b_2\overrightarrow{OB}$$ with $a_1+b_1=a_2+b_2=1$ by the proposition.

Next, let's consider $\overrightarrow{OC_1}+\overrightarrow{OC_2}$. Since $O$, $C_1$, $C_2$ are all on line $\ell$, vectors $\overrightarrow{OC_1}$ and $\overrightarrow{OC_2}$ are collinear with $A$ and $B$, so is their sum. We have $$\begin{align}
\overrightarrow{OC_1}+\overrightarrow{OC_2} &=a_1\overrightarrow{OA}+b_1\overrightarrow{OB}+a_2\overrightarrow{OA}+b_2\overrightarrow{OB} \\
&=(a_1+a_2)\overrightarrow{OA}+(b_1+b_2)\overrightarrow{OB}
\end{align}$$
However, the sum of the decomposition coefficients of $\overrightarrow{OC_1}+\overrightarrow{OC_2}$ is $a_1+a_2+b_1+b_2=1+1=2$, not $1$ any more, a violation of the proposition.

> The proposition of the text should be correct, so where was I wrong in applying the proposition? How to reconcile this contradiction?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: There is no contradiction, since $\overrightarrow{OC_1} + \overrightarrow{OC_2}$ is not a vector from $O$ to a point on line $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$, and thus $a+b=1$ may not apply.

Comment: @player3236: why is $\overrightarrow{OC_1} + \overrightarrow{OC_2}$ not a vector from $O$ to a point on $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad. In the case where $O,A,B,C_1,C_2$ are collinear, the decomposition rule should be "there exists a decomposition where the sum of decomposition coefficients is $1$" instead of the sum always being $1$. I believe the ambiguity of the subject of "*can* be decomposed" is at fault here.

To illustrate this, consider the case where all these points are on the real line, so they can be represented as real directed numbers. Let $O = 0, A = 2, B = 3$. Then $\overrightarrow {OA} = 2, \overrightarrow {OB}=3$.

Take the case $C_1 = A =2$. Then a decomposition could be $\overrightarrow {OC_1} = 1\cdot\overrightarrow {OA} + 0 \cdot\overrightarrow {OB}$, with sum of decomposition coefficients $1$. Another decomposition could be $\overrightarrow {OC_1} = 0\cdot\overrightarrow {OA} + \frac23\cdot\overrightarrow {OB}$, with sum of decomposition coefficients $\frac23$. We can even decompose it as $\overrightarrow {OC_1} = -2\cdot\overrightarrow {OA} + 2\cdot\overrightarrow {OB}$, with sum of decomposition coefficients $0$. This shows that the decomposition is not unique. Most decompositions violate the "rule", but there still exists a decomposition with sum of decomposition coefficients $1$.

For example, if we have $C_2 = B = 3$, we can say:

$$\overrightarrow {OC_1} = 1\cdot\overrightarrow {OA} + 0 \cdot\overrightarrow {OB}$$
$$\overrightarrow {OC_2} = 0\cdot\overrightarrow {OA} + 1 \cdot\overrightarrow {OB}$$
$$5=\overrightarrow {OC_1}+\overrightarrow {OC_2}  = 1\cdot\overrightarrow {OA} + 1 \cdot\overrightarrow {OB} = -2\cdot \overrightarrow {OA} + 3 \cdot\overrightarrow {OB}$$

where the latter decomposition satisfies the rule but not the former.

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much for the clarification.